# Comparing the age distribution between my sample and population

Tags: age

my data has 3 variables: category (age categories), frequency from my sample (count_s) and frequency from the population (count_s). The "category" variable has 6 categories where I have categorised ages in bins of 0-15 years, 15-30, 30-45, 45-60, 60-75 and more than 75. Which statistics do I use to compare the sample ages and population ages?

[image: my dataframe]

Comment: Chi-squared will do it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Calculating_the_test-statistic